# can we write own language constructs in C#?

Tags: c#

i'd like to know if it is possible to implement own language constructs (like lock or foreach) in C#?

The idea behind is that i want to mark start and end of a block of operations.
instead of writing

```
startblock("blockname");
  blabla();
  andsoon();
endblock();
```

i'd like to write something like

```
block("blockname"){
  blabla();
  test();
}
```

thank you!

Comment: What should the semantics be in your sample? Many things can already expressed easily with existing language constructs and most of the time there is no need for adding something to the language.

Comment: it is only for tracing. i want to trace a start message before a block of instructions and an end message after this block, so my trace viewer can group all the elements inside a block together.
for example i trace a start-message called "calculate invoices" then do all the stuff and then trace an end message so the block gets closed.
i dont want to use explicit "start" and "end" functions because people tend to forget one of these...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For which purpose do you need it? Just for clarity of writing and clean code?
C# is not extensible language.
With using you can achieve that nicely:

```
using (new Context("block name"))
{
    // do your staff here
}

class Context : IDisposable
{
    public Context(string name)
    {
        // init context
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // finish work in context
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

No you can't. But there is kind of workaround using `IDisposable`. You can create a class which will represent block start in constructor and block end in `Dispose`. Then you wrap the code into `using`. More here:

- http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/05/misusing-idisposable-beyond-resource.html
- http://scottbilas.com/blog/bracketing-operations-with-idisposable/

Comment: +1 Abusing `IDisposable` for marking code regions has worked very well for me.

Comment: Quick question, IDisposable only works within the using block right, otherwise it will be called when garbage collected?

Comment: @Akash - it doesn't force you to use the using block, so one can still forget to call Dispose(). Dispose() is unrelated to the GC - when an object is collected by the GC, Finalize()/~this() is called.

Comment: Yes, it's meant to be used with the using block. You can use it like this: `using(startblock("name")){...}` if startblock returns an IDisposable object.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, so if I forget to call Dispose, when it is called?

Comment: And if performance is critical, you might consider using an `IDisposable` struct instead of a class - no extra object allocation.

Comment: @Akash - if you forget to call dispose, it is never called. A solution is to use the pattern of `void Dispose(bool disposing)`, which gets called from both the Dispose() and Finalize() methods, and ensures that the object gets disposed by one or the other. (See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx)

Comment: @Pent, I certainly wouldn't call that "abusing" `IDisposable`, even in jest. This uses IDisposable to clean up state, which is precisely what it is for. Would be a minor point if there weren't so many cases where people do abuse it, and treat it as something to do with GC, which makes such joking misleading here.

Comment: @Mark. Or better yet, have all unmanaged resources accessed via a managed wrapper (one resource each), have it implement both a finaliser and idisposable, have the managed class never need a finaliser, and avoid the anti-pattern of disposing of managed and unmanaged resources at the same time.

Answer (score 9):

Another option is passing a function to a handler.

```
private void block(string name, Action action)
{
    startblock(name);
    action();
    endblock();
}
```

Followed by:

```
block("blockname", () =>
                {
                    blabla();
                    test();
                });
```

Keep in mind, this may be an indication that you need an **abstract class** (or a regular base class), and allow overriding of that method.

Comment: @Akash Kava - not too quick. It took me quite a few minutes, I wanted to make sure it compiles `:)`

Comment: I think you mean `startblock(name)`

Answer (score 1):

Nemerle provides constructs like this. It is not too dissimilar from C#.

Comment: @reverseblade: Good to know, seems most .NET langs are dying (like my IronScheme). C# must be sufficient :)

Comment: +1 I created [a post](http://codecrafter.blogspot.com/2011/04/more-macros-in-nemerle.html) that solved this exact problem in Nemerle.